# Calculating mean value with field calculator for selected records using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser, statistics

I want to calculate the mean value in the field `z`  which has Type `Zero` and write it in Ground field.

How can I do that with arcpy?

[image]

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Shapefile, "layer")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layer", "NEW_SELECTION","Type = 0")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("layer", "Ground", "mean(!{0}!)".format("Z"), "PYTHON_9.3")
```

I have got error for this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, a [Search Cursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) is used within a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to collect all of the `Z` values `if Type == 0`. [`np.mean()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) is used to find the mean value within the list.

Once the mean value is determined, use an [Update Cursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) to write the mean value to the `Ground` field `if Type == 0`.

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np

fc = r'C:\temp\temp.gdb\some_featureclass'

# Find the mean value for the "Z" field if "Z" == 0
val = np.mean([x[0] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("Z", "Type")) if x[1] == 0])

# Write the value to the "Ground" field if "Type" == 0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["Type", "Ground"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == 0:
            row[1] = val
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your approach won't work,  as you are trying to apply a mean over a set of selected records to a each of the selected rows. but you need to have computed the mean prior to this calculation.  A better way is to run your data through the Summary statistics tool grouping by your type field. You can then join the resulting table to your original layer.